# How can I make a server time app with SignalR

Tags: signalr

I'm leaning SignalR. How can I write a simple app so user can see server-time in real-time using Hub. Every 1 second, server will send time from server to connected clients

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Did you wrote anything?

Answer (score 3):

you can do when you using thread.

Example Hub Class:

```
public class ServerTime : Hub
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Write);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Clients.settime(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Example Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var time = $.connection.serverTime;
        $("#btnTest").click(function () {
            time.start();
        });

        time.settime = function (t) {
            $("#Time").html(t);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
<div id="Time"></div>
<input id="btnTest" type="button" value="Test"/>
```

Thread will start working when you click btnTest.
Thread sends message to page everysecond.

Comment: So what happens if another user access this page? So that time we have two threads start?

Comment: You don't need to start two threads. Because It will send ServerTime all connected users when thread first started. To start thread once is enough.

Comment: I am also new to signalR. I tried your example with exact code above but I keep getting the following error:

"SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()";

My references are all correct. I am stumped!

Comment: @sinanakyazici As vNext pointed out this code will NOT work properly for more than one client since multiple Threads will be started. You are correct that SignalR will send messages to all connected clients, but this will not stop the server side thread start code from being executed every time a new client connects.

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener and RAISE AN EVENT when a NOTIFICATION is added :) Thus you would not have to continuously check the database :)

Answer (score 0):

In Global.asax in the `Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` method create a background thread and start it.  In that thread you will need to do this to get access to your hub:

```
IConnectionManager connectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver
                                         .Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
dynamic clients = connectionManager.GetClients<ServerTime>();
clients.settime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
```

NB `DateTime.UtcNow` is nearly always preferable since it doesn't leap around twice a year.