# SignalR notification system

Tags: c#, signalr

This is my first time playing around with SignalR. I am trying to build a notification system where the server checks at regular intervals to see if there is something (query database) to broadcast and if there is then it broadcasts it to all the clients. 
I came across **[this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424967/how-can-i-make-a-server-time-app-with-signalr)** and was wondering if modifying the code to make a DB call at a particular interval was indeed the right way to do it. If not is there a better way to do it?

I did see a lot of Notification related questions posted here but none with any code in it. Hence this post.

This is the exact code that I am using:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Notify);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        List<CDCNotification> notifications = new List<CDCNotification>();
        while (true)
        {
            notifications.Clear();
            notifications.Add(new CDCNotification() 
                { 
                    Server = "Server A", Application = "Some App", 
                    Message = "This is a long ass message and amesaadfasd asdf message", 
                    ImgURL = "../Content/Images/accept-icon.png" 
                });
            Clients.shownotification(notifications);
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
        }
    }
}
```

I am already seeing some weird behaviour where the notifications come more often than they are supposed to. Even though I am supposed to get it every 20s I get it around 4-5 secs and I get multiple messages.
Here is my client:

```
var notifier = $.connection.notificationHub;
notifier.shownotification = function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, sample) {
        var output = Mustache.render("<img class='pull-left' src='{{ImgURL}}'/> <div><strong>{{Application}}</strong></div><em>{{Server}}</em> <p>{{Message}}</p>", sample);
        $.sticky(output);
    });
};

$.connection.hub.start(function () { notifier.start(); });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of notes:

1. As soon as a second client connects to your server there will be 2 threads sending the notifications, therefore if you ave more than one client you will have intervals smaller than 20s
2. Handling thread manually within ASP.NET is considered bad practice, you should avoid this if possible
3. In general this smells a lot like polling which is kind of the thing SignalR lets you get rid of since you don't need to signal the server/client

In order to solve this you need todo something like this (again, threads in a web application are generally not a good idea):

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
  public static bool initialized = false;
  public static object initLock = new object();

  public void Start()
  {
    if(initialized)
      return;

    lock(initLock)
    {
      if(initialized)
        return;

      Thread thread = new Thread(Notify);
      thread.Start();

      initialized = true;
    }
  }

  public void Notify()
  {
    List<CDCNotification> notifications = new List<CDCNotification>();
    while (true)
    {
      notifications.Clear();
      notifications.Add(new CDCNotification() { Server = "Server A", Application = "Some App", Message = "This is a long ass message and amesaadfasd asdf message", ImgURL = "../Content/Images/accept-icon.png" });
      Clients.shownotification(notifications);
      Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }
  }
}
```

The **static** initialized flag prevents multiple threads from being created. The locking around it is to ensure that the flag is only set once.

Comment: Thank you for that informative response. I agree this def. seems a little like long polling but the reason I had to do it this way is because the clients (Windows Services) are hosted in a different domain and cannot hit this site. The only thing i am achieving is sending get requests from the hundreds of clients. This way, stuff will be pushed only when it is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on the same task over here. Instead of continuously checking the database, I created my own events and listener, where an event is RAISED when a NOTIFICATION IS ADDED :) What do you think about that?

Comment: what i ended up doing is i have my windows service fires off an event on my website everytime something interesting happens and the hub on my site broadcasts that message to anyone on the site using the JS client.

Comment: my problem is that i am changing a label value and it works on all browsers except on IE (i would have to move the cursor on the window)

Comment: yes var log = $('#log');
            hub.newNotification = function (value) {
                log.append($('<li/>').text(value));
            };

Comment: Weird. Is it a particular version of IE or all?

Comment: my problem disappeared! I included something else in my jquery script and all works fine